# Android app and Web Interaction idea

Tags: android, web, interface

I am new to android development, I have a website that is for online shopping and I want to make an android app so the smart phone users can also access it. It will use something like PHP post/get, JSON, JavaScript to get values from server and submit forms from app. My question is after doing all these, mean HTTP Connection and all that, is there any need to make a special website for mobile device too, that will be compatible with mobile device? or no need of this, just to open it in mobile app? I have googled it but can't find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of visitors will visit the normal site instead of installing a unknown app.

It's your own choose, if i have the the choice i would choose both (web and app).
I think it's important to have a user and mobile friendly website.

At least you could make your website responsive so that user have the choice whether they will install a Native app or use the 'web' app.

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same question.
Apps are good-looking and functional.
But the thing is, especially in China, almost everybody around me uses "Wechat" as a daily app. The most important thing Wechat can provide is an entry. By establishing an official accounts, customers can be easily linked to your mobile website. And 1)it's way more convenience than Apps. 2)Mobile website has a less developing cost than an App. 3)With HTML5 spreading to mobile terminals, the interfaces can be cool and the function can be amazing.
So, for middle/little companies, I personally recommend mobile website.